# Assigning a machine IP under linux

Tags: linux, networking, interface, ip

I have a machine with 3 interfaces, two public and one local. They are all from the same IP range. All externally accessible services on the machine use the internal IP.

However, when a process opens a connection to the outside world, the source address in the packets is set to that of the public interface which will be used to sends the packets out.

Is it possible under Linux to force all source addresses to be that of a particular interface, even if the packet then will be routed through an other interface?

Say we have a machine with 3 interfaces, A.B.C.1, A.B.C.2, A.B.C.3. Of these A.B.C.1 and A.B.C.2 are connected to the Internet (and A.B.C.0/24 is routed to them). All services on the machine listen to A.B.C.3. Is it possible to guarantee that all packets originating on the machine will have the source address of A.B.C.3, even if they will leave the machine via A.B.C.1 or A.B.C.2 ?

Specifying the source address when the socket for the outgoing connection is opened is not a solution; we're talking about existing programs which can not be changed. Also, it should work for ICMP as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `iptables`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j SNAT --to A.B.C.3
```

If the `iptables` service is not running, it can be activated via the following command:

```
sudo service iptables restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into that. However, on the A.B.C.3 there are other, physically different machines using other addresses from the A.B.C.* range. I do not want their outgoing packets to be translated. That is, if machine at A.B.C.9 uses the default route of A.B.C.3, I want its packets to leave as A.B.C.9, only the machine with the 3 interfaces should be forced to use A.B.C.3 for all outgoing packets. I guess I will need to dig into the iptables (which is active, as a firewall) and the NAT table (which I've never used).